# Node.js and SSL with Restler

Tags: javascript, rest, node.js

I have installed latest version of Node.js and I still have problems with SSL and Restler. Where's the problem? Thank you!

**Request**

```
var restler = require('./lib/restler');

restler.get('https://example.com/', {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'pass'
}).on('complete', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

**Response**

```
WARNING: SSL not supported in your version of node JS

node.js:54
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer
    at Client._readImpl (net.js:144:14)
    at Client._onReadable (net.js:424:22)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:153:10)
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? Are you running on MacOSX, Ubuntu, Windows? Do you have the dev version of libssl installed? Node will happily compile without the ssl headers, but of course ssl won't work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL support in node.js is buggy and incomplete:

http://jsconf.eu/2010/speaker/techniques_for_a_single_stack.html

I think you have to wait until it is stable.